# how to alias npm with node? Cannot run npm without 'node npm'

Tags: docker, npm, mit-scratch

I use multistage build with a busybox shell to copy node files in scratch.
I am able to run node, and npm with `node npm` command. However, I am unable to run node npm without being in the same path getting this error:

```
/ # node npm
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:949
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/npm'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.4.0
```

How do I correctly alias `node npm` so I can run `npm` without adding node infront?

FULL BUILD:

```
FROM amd64/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:b2339eee806d44d6a8adc0a790f824fb71f03366dd754d400316ae5a7e3ece3e as USER
# Create User in Ubuntu
RUN useradd -u 10001 node
RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global/bin -p

FROM node:alpine3.16 AS node

WORKDIR /app/
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]
COPY ["src/", "./src/"]
COPY ["/public", "./public/"]
RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]

FROM scratch
# Export Path
ENV PATH="/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
# Copy User Files
COPY --from=USER /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=USER /etc/group /etc/group
COPY --chown=node:node --from=USER /home/node /home/node

# BusyBox Static Binary
COPY --from=ghcr.io/antyung88/scratch-sh:stable /lib /lib
COPY --from=ghcr.io/antyung88/scratch-sh:stable /bin /bin
# Node
COPY --from=node /usr/lib /usr/lib
COPY --from=node /usr/local/share /usr/local/share
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
COPY --from=node /usr/local/include /usr/local/include
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

# Copy Files
COPY --chown=node:node --from=node /app ./app

WORKDIR /app
USER node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm .

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: What error do you get when running `npm` directly?

Comment: sh: npm: not found

Comment: npm only works if I put node infront while being in the same directory

Comment: I'm not sure what benefit you're getting by using a `FROM scratch` final image, but then `COPY --from=node` almost its entire filesystem in.  Does starting the final image `FROM node` work better?